# How do I iterate through an array and then a second level array of objects in php?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hey so I'm trying to figure out the following and I can't find it out. :

I have a collection called $jugadores. This collection has multiple objects like this one:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "apodo": "Lora",
    "nombre": "Ignacio",
    "apellido": null,
    "dob": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "pos": "arq",
    "goles": 19,
    "partidos": 24,
    "victorias": 13,
    "derrotas": 8,
    "empates": 3,
    "rachasres": [
      {
        "racha": "win",
        "conteo": 3,
        "inicio": 1,
        "fin": 3
      },
      {
        "racha": "lose",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 4,
        "fin": 4
      },
      {
        "racha": "draw",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 5,
        "fin": 5
      },
      {
        "racha": "lose",
        "conteo": 2,
        "inicio": 6,
        "fin": 7
      },
      {
        "racha": "win",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 8,
        "fin": 8
      },
      {
        "racha": "lose",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 9,
        "fin": 9
      },
      {
        "racha": "win",
        "conteo": 2,
        "inicio": 10,
        "fin": 11
      },
      {
        "racha": "lose",
        "conteo": 2,
        "inicio": 12,
        "fin": 13
      },
      {
        "racha": "win",
        "conteo": 2,
        "inicio": 14,
        "fin": 15
      },
      {
        "racha": "lose",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 16,
        "fin": 16
      },
      {
        "racha": "draw",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 17,
        "fin": 17
      },
      {
        "racha": "lose",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 18,
        "fin": 18
      },
      {
        "racha": "win",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 19,
        "fin": 19
      },
      {
        "racha": "draw",
        "conteo": 1,
        "inicio": 20,
        "fin": 20
      },
      {
        "racha": "win",
        "conteo": 4,
        "inicio": 21,
        "fin": 24
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to build the HTML table to display this data, sort it, etc, and In all other tables for different stats, I just use foreach and map keys in each column. Like this:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($jugadores as $jugador)
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center"></td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ $jugador->apodo }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ $jugador->nombre }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ $jugador->partidos }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ $jugador->golAvg }}</td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

But in this new table, I need to go one level deeper and do a foreach for the "rachasres" key for each player. And I can't find the right syntax, I'm not sure how to do it.

My objective is to end up with a table like this. Considering of course that this is not the only player, so I need to loop over players, and then over each object.:

| Jugador | Streak | Count | Start day | End day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lora | win | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| Lora | lose | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| Lora | draw | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| Lora | lose | 2 | 6 | 7 |
| Lora | win | 1 | 8 | 8 |

BTW, this is a study project so any recommendation is welcomed including if my input data is not ideal

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to loop 2 times:

```php
@foreach ($jugadores as $jugador)
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">Jugador</td>
            <td class="text-center">Streak</td>
            <td class="text-center">Count</td>
            <td class="text-center">Start day</td>
            <td class="text-center">End day</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($jugador['rachasres'] as $rachasre)
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $jugador->apodo }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $rachasre->racha }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $rachasre->conteo }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $rachasre->inicio }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ $rachasre->fin }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That is what I tried and I kept getting errors. Turns out the problem was that you can't access <td class="text-center">{{ $rachasre->racha }}</td> like this, you have to do it passing the key like this. <td class="text-center">{{ $rachasre['racha']}}</td>